# how to get value from one textfield to another

Tags: java, sql

i want to get the values from the textfield from the class DATAENTRY into my current class SoilTable in order to make the table work

```
private void btgetinvActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



    try {                                 //my class DATAENTRY from which i have to fetch the value of textfield tf_rm_id
        DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
        Connection con = util.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(box_no)as total from mut_det WHERE rm_id = ?");
        ResultSet rs;
        String rm = tf_rm_id.getText().trim();
        stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(rm));
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            tf_boxno.setText(rs.getString("total"));
        }
```

this is my class where i want to substitute the value of textfield tf_rm_id for the ? parameter

```
      try {                                               // My current class SoilTable
        DBUtil util = new DBUtil(); 
        Connection con = util.getConnection(); 
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from soil_det where rm_id=?");
        String rmn = (tf_rm_id.getText() == null || tf_rm_id.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : tf_rm_id.getText();
        stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(rmn));
```

Comment: is the textfield declared
 as private ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well (your code is not very clear) I would create a method and return that value.

In your other class I would create an object of that class and call that method  then assign it to another value if you want to, like:

//DATAENTRY class

```
  public String getVal()
  {
      return tf_rm_id;
   }
```

//SoilTable

```
 DATAENTRY textFieldVal = new DATAENTRY();

 String strTextFieldVal = textFieldVal.getVal();
 //assigned a new value
 strTextFieldVal = " field value manipulated";

//or display it directly:

 System.out.println("Value recieved: "+textFieldVal.getVal());
```